# HTTPGET for mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

Are all MVC Controller actions ,decorated with [HttpGet] by default internally?

Or

Should I explicitly add the attribute to all controller actions to avoid post on the same?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC if you do not specify the method, it will accept all http verbs. Usually is a used by `get`.

To specify a http verb, you should decorate the action method with the appropriate attribute, for sample, for a `POST` method, you should use `HttpPost` as the code bellow.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ProductViewModel product)
{
    return View();
}
```

There also verbs like:

- `HttpPut` for `PUT`
- `HttpDelete` for `DELETE`
- `HttpPatch` for
  `PATCH`

Take a look at [Request Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to know more about.

Answer (score 0):

The default verb is Get for the controllers. I would recommended that you place a verb for each Controller Action ( [HttpGet], [HttpPut], [HttpPost], [HttpDelete] ), to help with reading the code without guessing what the Actions is doing.